# Typescript: Make Generic Typed Parameter Flow From Function to Function

Tags: typescript

Consider the following code ( also on [TS Play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=9&ssc=1&pln=10&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgApQPYAcDOAeASUgFsA+ZAbwChlbkcIAbCBSAEyImIH4AuZTsSoBfKlRgBXEK2AYQyYnADWEAEoQwEqCAAUWTLn7psOAJSUadYDGR6DOAHQNmrCBxLnqdb8igat8vomTkws7IKWtKKRvv7ayADkCSJiktJgsvISDIQkpDox2dDGhmj2uVzkALyUop4xCHI4YLFgAGpwjMg1iirqmto6RVAlZgDcMX4D8lMdjBPRoJCwiCgAsgCeghbeCMBgG-wJzVCgAOYJADSTcBkgZ-wgEsQARtApVI0gzfShru5cbrIIp4TaCfKmKhAA) )

```js
interface Props<Item> {
    selectedItem?: Item
}

function makeReturn(props: Props) { // complaints : Generic type 'Props<Item>' requires 1 type argument(s).
    if (props.selectedItem) {
        return props.selectedItem
    }

    return ''
}

function useAutosuggest<Item>(
    userProps: Props<Item> = {}
) {
    const retVal = makeReturn(userProps);
    return retVal;
}

interface MyItem {
    city: 'string',
    rating: number
}

const selectedItem = useAutosuggest<MyItem>()
```

My thought process is – what do I do, so that the `makeReturn` function be able to know that `selectedItem` should be of whatever type `useAutosuggest` takes in (in this case `MyType`). I'm not sure if I'm thinking correctly. If I am, what to do to act upon this thought process, if not what am I thinking wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main things you're looking for is function generics and return types, but there's a couple other things that will help.

First, I recommend using "T" instead of `Item`. You don't have to, but it's conventional, and it makes it clearer to read in this case (I kept wondering "where is the `Item` type!):

```
interface Props<T> {
    selectedItem?: T
}
```

To your main question, you needed to make the function generic:

```
function makeReturn<T>(props: Props<T>): T|undefined {
    if (props.selectedItem) {
        return props.selectedItem
    }

    return undefined
}
```

or technically this is fine too (assuming `props` is never null or undefined):

```
function makeReturn<T>(props: Props<T>): T|undefined {
    return props.selectedItem
}
```

Note how the return type is `T|undefined`. In your example you returned an empty string. You can't do that in TypeScript without a warning or an error.

I tweaked the next function a bit (but there are multiple ways to skin the cat):

```
function use<T>(userProps?: Props<T>): T|undefined {
    return makeReturn(userProps || {})
}
```

Full code ([playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=23&pc=1#)):

```
interface Props<T> {
    selectedItem?: T
}

function makeReturn<T>(props: Props<T>): T|undefined {
    if (props.selectedItem) {
        return props.selectedItem
    }

    return undefined
}

function use<T>(userProps?: Props<T>): T|undefined {
    return makeReturn(userProps || {})
}

interface MyItem {
    city: 'string',
    rating: number
}

const selectedItem = use<MyItem>()
```